# time complexity when working with python string

Tags: python, time

I'm analysing the complexity of string concatination for different methods and what I notice.

```
%%time
sent = ""
word = "hello "
num = 100000
for _ in range(num):
    sent += word
```

this method takes 20ms

```
%%time
sent_1 = "".join([word] * num)
```

the second method takes 4 ms and

```
%%time
sent_2 = ""
for _ in range(num//5):
    sent_2 = sent_2 + word + word + word + word + word
```

the third method takes 208 ms

`sent==sent_1==sent_2`
gives me True

can someone explain why I get such results

Comment: "can someone explain why I get such results" What needs explaining? What do you think the results should be like instead, and why? I notice you wrote "time complexity" in the title; did you try using different values of `num`, to assess the big-O complexity of each approach?

Comment: Repeated string concatenation (using the `+` symbol) in Python is very slow.  Using `.join()` is much faster.  It's that simple.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `str` values are immutable. *But*, CPython has an optimization that detects that `sent + word` is being assigned back to `sent`, and so updates `sent` in-place anyway.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I thought that 
for _ in range(num):
    sent += word
should give the same time as
for _ in range(num//5):
    sent_2 = sent_2 + word + word + word + word + word

Comment: Ah, then the question is basically about the special-case optimization of `+=` for strings. This is a common question, but I'm struggling to find a proper canonical. But see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791931.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sent2 + word + word + word + word + word` creates multiple temporary `str` objects, roughly equivalent to

```
t1 = sent2 + word
t2 = t1 + word
t3 = t2 + word
t4 = t3 + word
sent_2= t4 + word
```

Creating all these objects (and copying the ever-growing values of one temporary value into another) results in a quadratic runtime.

`''.join([word] * num)`, on the other hand, gets all the strings to concatenate at once in a single list, so it can allocate *one* result string and copy the substring in place in linear time.

The first example,

```
for _ in range(num):
    sent += word
```

*should* be equivalent to repeated concatenation. But, CPython in particular optimizes this by recognizing that nobody can access the value of `sent` while `sent + word` is being computed, so it "cheats" and updates `sent` in place, with no new string being allocated to assign back to `sent`. This means you still have a linear-time operation, like `''.join`, but with extra overhead due to iterating over the string in Python rather than at the C level of the interpreter.